# how do execute gdb call function

Tags: gdb

Error in sourced command file:
No symbol "saveServer" in current context. How to resolve this?

Ubuntu 16.04

```
catch signal SIGBUS SIGFPE SIGILL SIGINT SIGSEGV SIGSYS SIGSYS SIGXCPU SIGXFSZ
commands
set $MyVar = 1
call saveServer()
end
set $MyVar = 0
run

if $MyVar == 0
quit
end
```

Comment: in the snippet you posted, there is no definition of g_game, so it can't be called. you're gonna have to post more code for someone to help you.

Comment: [mcve] raises the chance of an answer significantly.

Comment: What is the output of the gdb command `ptype saveServer`

Comment: What language is the program written in?